# Angular 4 resetting form after update - keeping ngModel values (using ngForm)

Tags: angular

I feel like this should be simple but I can't find anything (at least without a lot of overhead coding) for my particular use case.  Basically I have an Update Profile page that is not a modal.  Once the user updates, I want the form to be reset back to original state and with the current values, in case the user wants to do some more edits.

I'm using ngForm's `reset()` (also tried `resetForm()`).  This resets it to pristine, etc., but it also removes all of the values in the inputs.  On each of the inputs I'm using `[(ngModel)]="userRecord.phone"`, etc.  My `userRecord` is still correct.

Is there a simple way to keep or get back the model values after reset?

```
onSubmit(event, profileForm: NgForm) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const myTempVar = this.userRecord;
  this.userRecord.put()
    .catch((e) => {
      this.isProcessing = false;
      return Observable.of(false);
    })
    .subscribe((response) => {
      this.displayConfirmation = 'Profile has been updated successfully.'
      this.isProcessing = false;
      this.userRecord = myTempVar;
    }, (err) => {
      console.log('There was an error saving', err);
      this.displayError = 'Unknown error.  Please refresh this page and try again.'
      this.isProcessing = false;
    });
}
```

If it helps to visualize, here is the original screen before submitting:
[image: original]

Here it is after submitting, if I do an ngForm `reset()`:
[image: with reset]

Here it is if I don't do a reset.  I was hoping it to be like this, except also pristine and get the submit button enabled again (although now I'm noticing that's not happening if I do a reset, anyways. :-( ).
[image: without reset]

Comment: Do you apply the new values to the `userRecord` variable when user submit the from?

Comment: Yes, exactly John - don't want the data changed.

Comment: Praveen, I don't apply any new values to the userRecord after submit, but I could refresh from the DB I suppose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before your form submit you could clone your form data into some tmp object:

```
tmpFormData: someType = Object.assign({}, currentData);
```

Then after you do `reset()` you can do `yourForm.patchValue(valuesFromtmpFormDateObject)`

Comment: Thanks!  I don't have ngForm `patchValue()` but `setValue()` did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Do this after submit is successful.

```
const myTempVar = this.userRecord;
this.form.reset();
this.userRecord = myTempVar;
```

This should reassign the value to model.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work, I'm not sure at that point it knew to refresh the ngModel values?(actually not sure why that didn't work, seems like it should have!

Comment: sure, added to question